# Manually create a colormap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I am using a scatter plot to create a heat map. I have used the `Greys` colormap to display the dense area's as black and the light areas as white. So the areas with more xy points as black and less xy as white.

This works fine but the areas without data is too white for this application. Because I have background data displayed on the plot, if the map is too white this data is very hard to see.

Therefore, I'm trying to create a colormap were the contrast between black and white isn't so great. I'd like it go to between black and a very light grey.

Initial code is shown here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

x = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10)]
y = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10)]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.grid(False)

data1,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 10, range = np.array([(0,80), (0,80)]))
ax1.imshow(data1, interpolation = 'gaussian', origin = 'lower', extent = [0,100,0,100], cmap = 'Greys')
```

[image]

The areas without xy data are very white and anything displayed in these areas are hard to see. So I imported my own colormap were the lightest colour is grey.

```
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["gainsboro","lightgrey","lightgrey","silver","silver","darkgray","darkgray","gray","gray","dimgray","dimgray","black","black"])
```

This is ok but I'd like like there to be a bigger contrast from black to light grey. Specifically, I'd like it to go lighter grey. The areas with no data (which would be white) are too dark. It only goes from grey to black.

[image]

Is there another way to create a colormap that has a bigger contrast in colors that doesn't go completely to white. I know it sounds vague but I was hoping it would go from black down to a very light grey. Is there a way to manually play with the contrast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colormap can also be created with an starting and an ending color using the same method you used. Therefore, a colormap from light grey to black can be created with the method [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list):

> Make a linear segmented colormap with name from a sequence of colors which evenly transitions from colors[0] at val=0 to colors[-1] at val=1. N is the number of rgb quantization levels.

Therefore, the colormap can be defined like this:

```
cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom greys', [(.9,.9,.9),(0,0,0)], N=256)
```

The color extremes are in rgb tuples, where (1,1,1) is white and (0,0,0) is black.